# Given is markov chain - Determine the probability $f_1(n)$

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-theory, statistics, markov-chains

> Given is markov chain $\left\{X_n\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with
>   transition probabilities
>
> $$M= \begin{pmatrix} 
> 1/2   &   1/2   &   0   &   0   &   0   &   0   \\  
> 1/4   &   3/4   &   0   &   0   &   0   &   0   \\  
> 1/4   &   1/4   &   1/4 &   1/4 &   0   &   0   \\  
> 1/4   &     0   &   1/4 &   1/4 &   0   &   1/4 \\  
> 0     &     0   &   0   &   0   &   1/2 &   1/2 \\ 
> 0     &     0   &   0   &   0   &   1/2 &   1/2 
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Determine the probability $f_1(n)$ where you return to state $1$ after
>   $n$ steps  (for the first time).

I'm not sure how you can solve this because if I understood it correctly, we have $n$ steps and we are looking for a probability, so we have two unknowns...

Anyway, I think the correct way of calculating it is (don't miss the little exponent $n$ of that huge matrix!)

$$f_1(n) = \begin{pmatrix} 
1/2   &   1/2   &   0   &   0   &   0   &   0   \\  
1/4   &   3/4   &   0   &   0   &   0   &   0   \\  
1/4   &   1/4   &   1/4 &   1/4 &   0   &   0   \\  
1/4   &     0   &   1/4 &   1/4 &   0   &   1/4 \\  
0     &     0   &   0   &   0   &   1/2 &   1/2 \\ 
0     &     0   &   0   &   0   &   1/2 &   1/2 
\end{pmatrix}^n \cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Here I'm stuck again for the same reason, I see no way of calculating the probability...? : /

Comment: If the chain starts at $1$, the problem involves only a Markov chain on **two states**. And the computation becomes trivial.

Comment: @Did Does that mean I need to set $n=2$? If that's the case I don't see why :s

Comment: No. No idea why you translated what I said as such.

Comment: @Did : I don't think that particular confusion can be fully cleared up without pointing out that there should be a row vector on the left rather than a column vector on the right. The transition probabilities are not properly construed if it's a column vector on the right.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You do not think that, because you stay fixed on the matrix itself instead of focussing on the **pathwise properties** of the chain. Once you adopt this point of view, all your stuff about row vectors and column vectors becomes redundant and the remark in my comment, which yields directly the result, becomes embarrassingly obvious.

Comment: @Did : You cannot think about pathwise properties of the chain if you think the transition probabilities from the first state to the other states are given by the first column rather than by the first row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if the chain starts at state $1$ then it can return to the state in one step, i.e., $f_1(1) = 1/2$. Consider now that the chains goes to state $2$, once $X_n = 2$, the number of steps until the chain returns to state $1$ is distributed geometrically with $p=1/4$, hence 
$$
f_1(n) = \frac{1}{2}I\{n=1\}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{3}{4} \right)^{n-2}\frac{1}{4}I\{n\ge2\}
$$

Answer (score 3):

You need this:
$$
f_1(n) = \begin{pmatrix}
1, &
0, &
0, &
0, &
0, &
0
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 
1/2   &   1/2   &   0   &   0   &   0   &   0   \\  
1/4   &   3/4   &   0   &   0   &   0   &   0   \\  
1/4   &   1/4   &   1/4 &   1/4 &   0   &   0   \\  
1/4   &     0   &   1/4 &   1/4 &   0   &   1/4 \\  
0     &     0   &   0   &   0   &   1/2 &   1/2 \\ 
0     &     0   &   0   &   0   &   1/2 &   1/2 
\end{pmatrix}^n \cdot 
$$
What tells you it's done that way is that the rows add up to $1$ and the columns don't.

Then you can see that you have a Markov chain in which, once you're in state $1$ or state $2,$ you can never get to other states than $1$ and $2.$ And that means you only need to pay attention to the first two rows and the first two columns.

Comment: Thank you very much now also understand what @Did meant by his comment!